# How to display woocommerce products in list view, without image

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

How to display woocommerce products in list view, without image, both on shop page and single product page?
I tried a plugin 'woocommerce-product-table' but thumbnail is still visible on single product page.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that with removing two actions.

The first, for the shop loop

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_loop_product_thumbnail');
```

The second, for the product page

```
remove_action('woocommerce_before_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_show_product_images', 20);
```

Removing the image from the shop loop and the product page can lead to some unexpected behavior, if you know css you will have no problem fixing it.

Comment: Hi @Buttered_Toast, which file do we have to add this code into?

Comment: This code goes into the functions.php of your current active theme